# Convert a geom_tile in dotplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing several heatmaps in ggplot2 using `geom_tile`. They work great but what if instead of tiles (little rectangles) I want to have dots. My input is a binary matrix (converted in a table using `melt` function).
My x and y are discrete factors. How do I produce circles or dots instead of tiles.....any idea?

Thanks!

example:

```
dat=data.frame(sample = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c"), cond=c("x","y","z","x","y","z","x","y","z"),value=c("1","4","6","2","3","7","4","6","7"),score=c(0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1))
```

if I use the following plot:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = sample, y = cond, color = value)) + 
  geom_point()
```

I get the wrong plot. Instead, I would like to have or not have a dot where the score is 0 or 1 and color them by value factor.

Comment: Hi Jordan, please make your post reproducible: include a same of your data and code you've written so far to get your desired result. It's hard to help without knowing what you've tried so far!

Comment: The simplest solution is to use `geom_point()` instead of `geom_tile()`.

Comment: I edited with a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean to map *score* to your color aesthetic and not *value*, as written in your shared code.
Simply convert *color* to a factor in your initial aesthetics call:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = sample, y = cond, color = as.factor(score))) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image: color points as factor]

**EDIT:**
The user indicated that he would like to filter observations where *score* is not equal to 1, and then color the points by *value*. You can do so by adding the following pipe operation:

I assume you mean to map *score* to your color aesthetic and not *value*, as written in your shared code.
Simply convert *color* to a factor in your initial aesthetics call:

```
dat %>% 
filter(score == 1) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = sample, y = cond, color = as.factor(value))) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image: Modified Plot]

Note that there are only 3 levels of the factor *score* and we are missing level *b* from sample on the x-axis. Keep all levels by specifying `drop = FALSE` in `scale_x_discrete()`:

```
dat %>% 
  filter(score == 1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sample, y = cond, color = as.factor(value))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image: third plot with <code>drop = false</code>]

Comment: no, sorry for the confusion, but I would like to have a similar plot, but instead not have points when the score is 0 and have a point when the score is 1. All with fixed size. and then color them using a discrete palette of colors according to the value column

Comment: Then please specify in your original post. Be as clear as possible.

Comment: Yeah I am sorry but English is not my language and I am really trying to do my best. What I meant was "not showing points", not "filter out those scores". In the sample x axis I want to show also the empty b.

Comment: See the **EDITED** section of my answer, that should provide you what you need.